# Proper subgroup of simple groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

Not sure how to do this:

Fix integer n>1. Prove there exist only finitely many simple groups containing proper subgroups of index smaller than or equal to n.

Comment: Finite intersection [perserves finite index](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Index_satisfies_intersection_inequality). Consider the order of the overgroup in relation to the index of the [normal core](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Normal_core) of this proper subgroup in view of simplicity.

Comment: I've changed [tag:algebra] tag to [tag:abstract-algebra], since we don't use algebra tag anymore, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/473/the-use-of-the-algebra-tag/3081#3081) for details.

Answer (score 3):

If $G$ is a simple group containing a subgroup $H$ of index $m \le n$, then the action on cosets gives a homomorphism $G \to S_m$.  What can the kernel of this homomorphism be?