# Let $n>1$ be a fixed integer. Prove there are only finitely many simple groups (up to iso) containing a proper subgp of index $\leq n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Question: Let $n>1$ be a fixed integer.  Prove that there are only finitely many simple groups (up to isomorphism) containing a proper subgroup of index less than or equal to $n$.

Thoughts: The question was given a hint here: [Proper subgroup of simple groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227956/proper-subgroup-of-simple-groups)

If $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$ with index $m<n$, then $G$ acts on the left cosets of $H$ by left multiplication inducing a homomorphism from $\phi:G\rightarrow S_m$.  Since $G$ is simple, $\ker\phi$ is trivial, so $G\cong \leq S_m$, and so $|G|\leq m!$ since $|G|$ divides $m!$, and since $m<n$, we have  $m!<n!$... so does this mean that since $m!$ is finite, that there are only finitely many such $G$?

Comment: So $|G|\leq n!$. There are only finitely many possible groups of  any fixed finite order $k$, up to isomorphism, so you're done.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That's what I was thinking - I suppose it just seemed a bit too easy, like I was (as I typically am) missing something. :)
Thank you!